# A half gauge/speedometer animation using javascript

Tags: javascript, gauge

I am having a problem with a gauge "[click here](http://clients.pix10.com/demo/5paisa/index.html)", I need this gauge animated on change of amount given below the "GAUGE" not on "Turnover amount":

```
    function initGauge() {
    document.getElementById("class-code-name").innerHTML = "Gauge";
    demoGauge = new Gauge(document.getElementById("m_total"));
    demoGauge.setTextField(document.getElementById("m_total"));
    demoGauge.maxValue = 100;
    demoGauge.set(67.7);
};

function initDonut() {
    document.getElementById("class-code-name").innerHTML = "Donut";
    demoGauge = new Donut(document.getElementById("m_total"));
    demoGauge.setTextField(document.getElementById("preview-textfield"));
    demoGauge.maxValue = 100;
    demoGauge.set(67.7);
};
```

Comment: This is my JS code

Comment: Put that code in your question then

Answer (score 0):

Why create such code if it's already made?
http://jqueryrotate.com/ you only need a rotate function i suspect,
you already have the setgauge function with a value so this should solve that.